# Не могу нормально разобраться с git openshift

Tags: java, git, netbeans, telegram, openshift

Привет! В общем, создал бота для Telegram на java. Пришло время деплоя. Добавил облако в netbeans, подключил git репозиторий. Выполняю команду git->удаленный->вытолкнуть - возникает ошибка: [image: Ошибка 1]
Нагуглил, что надо сделать git push и git pull. Выполняю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем проблема? Пожалуйста, помогите, ибо уже 3-й день не могу врубиться!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не указана ветка в которую вы хотите отправить ваш код. Скорее всего в вашем случае поможет обычный:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Comment: Я уже совсем замучился, уже просто бесит - ничего не помогает, что бы я ни сделал, вылазят какие-то ошибки.......

Comment: Похоже на то что Вы забыли проиндексировать изменения и сделать коммит, прежде чем выталкивать изменения в репозиторий. Что показывает     git status ?

Comment: оказалось, что у меня были проблемы с файлом id_rsa. Никто нигде не пишет, что его надо как-то создавать.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала проверьте удаленные репозитории командой

```
git remote
```

Скорее всего вы увидите "origin"
Нужно стянуть все ссылки на ветки удалённого проекта. Сделать это можно при помощи

```
git fetch origin
```

Если у вас есть ветка, настроенная на отслеживание удалённой ветки, то вы можете использовать команду

```
git pull origin
```

При этом могут возникнуть конфликты, которые нужно разрешить.
После этого можно со спокойной душой делать

```
git push origin master
```

где origin - имя удаленного репозитория, master - ветка
А вообще есть хороший [туториал по гиту](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Ответ на вторую команду: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Это значит, что у вас происходит авторизация по SSH ключу, но по всей видимости на сервере просто нет вашего ключа, либо он невалидный. Его нужно сгенерировать и залить на сервер. Какой ресурс используется в качестве управления репозиториями? GitLab?

Comment: openshift. Сгенерировал, валидный. В папке .ssh нет файла id_rsa.pub. Хотя, видимо он нужен. Вопрос, как получить этот файл через putty?

Comment: @piller97, к сожалению, не работал с openshift, не могу подсказать в данном вопросе

Comment: оказалось, что у меня были проблемы с файлом id_rsa. Никто нигде не пишет, что его надо как-то создавать.